# Should I deploy cloud function with test files

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

Should I deploy cloud function written in golang with its test files? Is there any benefit or it just consumes more space in storage and adds on to the cost?

Asking about cost, I would also like to clarify my doubt - Does Cloud function source also count towards cost, space, quota or any limit? Currently, I have all functions at one place (sub-packaged) and I upload complete source code for each function. This is to manage golang dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I deploy cloud function written in golang with its test files?

I don't see any reason why you should

> Is there any benefit or it just consumes more space in storage and adds on to the cost?

I think it would only increase costs and delay your deployments, even if just a little bit

> Does Cloud function source also count towards cost, space, quota or any limit?

When you deploy a Cloud Function, [GCP stores the function's source code in Cloud Storage and stores a build on Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building#overview). You pay for this storage pricing, but it's very little, around $0.026 per GB per month according to this [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing).

Cloud functions also have some [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits). You can have 1000 functions per region.

---

I don't think you should worry too much about that pricing and quota limits. But if you want to, you can easily tell GCP to ignore some files when deploying your Cloud Function with [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore), using a `.gcloudignore` file (same syntax as `.gitignore`).

Example:

```yaml
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore

# Binaries
*.exe
*.exe~
*.dll

# test files
*_test.go
```

Comment: appreciate your response. Thanks.